# get vscode's monaco editor instance

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

For the online version of VS code (https://www.vscode.dev), I'd like to get a reference to the instance of the Monaco editor that it's using, so that I can interface with it in Javascript via Chrome's dev tools.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The instance is attached to the `.monaco-editor` element’s **parent** and there should be a `window.monaco` global that can provide access to the instance.

For example try running this:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.monaco-editor').parentElement;
const instance = monaco.editor.getEditors().find(editor => editor._domElement === container);
const currentText = instance.getValue();

instance.setValue(`@fregante was here \n ${currentText}`)
```

Unfortunately this won't help you directly because your website does not expose a `monaco` global, but it works on [Monaco’s website](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) for example.

Comment: Current VSCode has no global called `monaco`, did they remove it?

Comment: where is `container` used? Did you mean to use it in the `find` callback?

Answer (score 0):

Open the dev tools and use the picker to select the editor (or a part of it):

[image]